# Changing phpmail FROM header in order to show name and mail (with strip_tags)

Tags: php, email

I've been trying to get this format on mail header: "Some User < my@mail.com >", but I can't.

I have 2 variables that could retrieved from a form. These are `$_POST['form_email'])` and `$_POST['form_name'])`.

In php I have:

```
$headers = "From: ". strip_tags($_POST['form_email']) . "\r\n";
```

But I don't know how to add `$_POST['form_name'])` to `FROM`.

I think that maybe could be

```
$headers = "From: ". strip_tags($_POST['form_email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ". strip_tags($_POST['form_name']) . "\r\n";
```

...but don't work.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
 $headers = "From: ". strip_tags($_POST['form_name']) . " <". strip_tags($_POST['form_email']) . ">\r\n".
```

Comment: THANKS THANKS ...and THANKS. It works like a charm. 

I asked that because I have no idea how to deal with syntax. Hahaha.

Comment: please notice, that you have to sanitize your input. i.e. at the moment someone could do some mailinjections.

Comment: Thanks Raphael. It already has a machinery that prevent some injections (some hidden forms) and the script doesn't send anything if required fields are not completed.

Answer (score 0):

No idea of what you're trying to accomplish but [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) is an HTML manipulation function and e-mail headers must be plain text. The angle brackets at `<my@mail.com>` do not have any relationship with HTML.

You basically have to replace this:

```
$headers = "From: ". strip_tags($_POST['form_email']) . "\r\n";
```

... with something on this line:

```
$form_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form_name');
$form_email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form_email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if( !preg_match('/[\r\n]/u', $form_name) && $form_email ){
    $headers = sprintf('From: "%s" <%s>\r\n', $form_name, $form_email);
}else{
    // Don't send anything: either email injection attack or missing data
}
```

Done? Not yet. You still need to [encode `$form_name` properly](http://php.net/mb_encode_mimeheader) since it can contain quotes or non-ASCII characters. In fact, email is hard and you should not be trying to do it by yourself. A third-party package like [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks dude!. In a future I will use PHPMailer. I know that I need to encode $form_name properly in case of someone input some non-ASCII characters; at the moment I've developed a script that doesn't allow to input non ascii characters on the form.